# Change button value while entering in a textfield

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, button

I have a  button (styled as button with CSS). Next to it is an input field. I would like the button value to change dynamically as the user types a value in the textfield. What is the simplest way to do this?

My form:

```
<form>
    <div class="span-3" id="bid_btns">
        <div id="bid_button">
            <a href=""><?php echo $somethingwhichshouldchange; ?></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span-3 last" id="bid_btns">
        <div id="bid_field">
        <input type="text" class="title" name="bid_field" id="bid_field" maxlength="5"/>​
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't do this with just HTML and PHP; client-side scripting is usually done with Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make the button label/value change as you type, PHP is not going to help.  You need a script running in the browser - JavaScript.  If you use jQuery (you did ask for the simplest way, and jQuery makes this much simpler), you need some code to change the button as the input value changes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#bid_field").keyup(function(){
        $("#bid_btns").text($(this).val());
    });

});
```

This bit of code will change the html inside the #bid_btns button to whatever is typed into the #bid_field input.  If you're not familiar with jQuery, you can learn more by reading this article: http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Note - edited per BenM's siggestion.

Comment: Thanks. I'll do some more research on jQuery.

Comment: It's really useful - I have almost completely replaced Flash with jQuery.

Comment: Using `html()` is considered quite bad practice when you're working with unsanitized user input (such as this case) - I could easily break the layout by typing HTML into `#bid_field`. `.text()` is a much safer function to use here.

Comment: I didn't really consider that too much.  You can break the HTML in most browsers with FireBug or similar tools with no scripts at all.  Now, if you're pulling content from a database, *then* you have an excellent reason to use .text() over .html().

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a server side language, so you'll never be able to change a variable locally without re-serving the page. You need to investigate javascript to do what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve this. You just need to bind a function to the `onkeyup` event:

http://jsfiddle.net/Vt6N9/